# Too much white space before and after the equation when align and split used together

Tags: equations, align, split, white-space

I have the following latex code:

```
Applying Euler-Maruyama with step size $\tau>0$, we obtain the iteration scheme of $w_k$ and $P_k$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
    & w_{k+1} = w_k + \tau P_k,\\
    & P_{k+1} = P_k - \tau \nabla L(w_k) - \gamma \tau P_k + \sqrt{2\beta^{-1}\gamma \tau}\xi_{k}.
\end{split}    
\end{align*}
Adding the adaptive bias term
```

Which shows as:
[image]

My question is how can I decrease this white space before and after the equation block?

Comment: It doesn't look like the screenshot you posted was generated by the code snippet you've provided, as there is a paragraph indent before "Adding the adaptive bias term" in the screenshot that shouldn't be there if it had been generated by the code. Please fix either the screenshot or the code. It would be very helpful if you indicated (a) which document class you employ and (b) if your document uses a non-default value for line-spacing.

Comment: Incidentally, what's the purpose of the `split` environment inside the `align*` environment?

Comment: you should not use align for single line expressions

Comment: I can somewhat reproduce the picture if I load the `parskip` package and add a blank line before `\begin{align*}`. I don't like `parskip`, but it's personal opinion; a blank line before a math display is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this MWE I not see much white space before and after the equation. I have only used `align` enviroment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
Applying Euler-Maruyama with step size $\tau>0$, we obtain the iteration scheme of $w_k$ and $P_k$:
\begin{align*}
    &w_{k+1} = w_k + \tau P_k,\\
    &P_{k+1} = P_k - \tau \nabla L(w_k) - \gamma \tau P_k + \sqrt{2\beta^{-1}\gamma \tau}\xi_{k}. 
\end{align*}
Adding the adaptive bias term.
\end{document}
```

[image]